# Let p be a prime, $p\geq 7$. Show that there exists an integer $a$ such that $\big( \frac{a}{p} \big)=( \frac{a+2}{p} \big)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p be a prime, $p\geq 7$. Show that there exists an integer $a$ such that

$\big( \frac{a}{p} \big)=( \frac{a+2}{p} \big)$

(Legendre symbols).

I have tired to apply some theorems but it didn't give me much.

Comment: Here is the easy half of the proof: For p = 1 mod 4 take a = -1

Answer (score 2):

We try to construct a counterexample.

Since $1$ is a QR, we have to make $3$ an NR. Since $4$ is a QR, we have to make $2$ an NR. But then (if $p\ge 5$), $6$ is a QR.

Answer (score 1):

Landei in the comments gives the answer when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$: $a = -1$ works.

Suppose then that $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and that the claim is falls.  List the $\frac{p-1}2$ numbers $1,3,5,\dots,p-2$; since $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, this list has an odd number of entries.  If the claim is false, then since $1$ is a square, $3$ is not a square, $5$ is a square, etc., all the way to $p-2 \equiv -2 $ being a square.  Hence $-\frac12$ is a square (where by "$-\frac12$" I mean $\frac{p-1}2$).

But $5$ is a square, and so $-\frac52 = -\frac12 - 2$ is a square.